# how to make Make always use the most specific implicit rule?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

GNU Make manual says, the most "specific" implicit rule is chosen, which is a good thing.  Except...  if there is a rule for which no implicit prerequisites are needed to be made, it is chosen even if it is more "general".  See:

```
> touch existing
> cat Makefile
%.o: existing
 @echo general

foobar%.o: foobar%.i
 @echo specific

foobar%.i: ;
> rm foobar0.i
> make -r foobar0.o
general
> touch foobar0.i
> make -r foobar0.o
specific
```

IMHO, the most specific rule should be always chosen, regardless if there is 0 implicit prerequsites, and especially, whether such prerequisites already exist or not.  But I don't want to ask "why" here.

Instead, can someone suggest to me, how to force the desired behaviour.  I always want the most specific rule that applies, regardless.  Is there a way to force that?

Comment: The problem is that make always uses the most direct rule (fewest number of intermediate steps) as the first priority.  Using a more specific pattern rule (vs a more general one) is secondary, so only matters for chains with the same number of intermediate steps.  I'm not aware of any way to change these priorities.

Comment: What version of make are you using? The selection of rules changed between GNU make 3.81 and 3.82. The 'most specific' rule selection is a 3.82 behaviour I believe and not a 3.81 behaviour. If you invert the order of those two rules in your makefile do you get the behaviour you expect (if you are using 3.81 that is)?

Answer (score 0):

well, OK I can do this:

```
%.o: %.dummy
    @echo general

%.dummy: ;
```

I just don't like this kind of thing.  Is there a less ugly way.